# Issue with accessing parts of the array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I am trying to simply generate parts of an array with certain buttons. the code is not really working properly.

The code is as follows:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;



var clock_01:  Clock_one = new Clock_one ();
var clock_02:  Clock_two = new Clock_two ();
var clock_03:  Clock_three = new Clock_three ();
var clock_04:  Clock_four = new Clock_four ();
var socket_one:socket;
var clock_x_position = 100;
var clock_y_position = 100;
var clock_Array: Array = new Array ();


clock_Array.push( clock_01,clock_02,clock_03,clock_04);

var clock_counter = 2;
var v = 0;
var c = 0;
clock_display();

function clock_display()
{

    for (v; v < clock_counter; v++)
    {
        addChild(clock_Array[v]);
        clock_Array[v].x = clock_x_position;
        clock_Array[v].y = clock_y_position;
        clock_y_position +=  300;
        trace( clock_Array [v]);
        c = 0;
        trace(v);
    }

}

go_previous.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, go_back);
go_next.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, go_forward);

function go_back(l:MouseEvent)
{
    v -=  2;
    trace("The v after subtraction of 2" + v);
    trace("Going Previous Function Starts ----------------");



    for (v; v < clock_counter; v++)
    {
        removeChild(clock_Array[v]);
        trace("The v after child removal" + v);
        c++;
        if (c == 2)
        {

            v -=  4;
            trace("The v after subtraction in previous function is " + v);
            clock_y_position = 100;
            clock_counter -=  2;
            trace("The clock counter in previous function is" + clock_counter);
            clock_display();
        }
    }
}
function go_forward(l:MouseEvent)
{
    v -=  2;
    trace("Going Forwarf Function");

    for (v; v < clock_counter; v++)
    {
        removeChild(clock_Array[v]);
        trace("The v after subtraction in forward function is " + v);
        trace("it atleast goes here");
        c++;
        if (c == 2)
        {

            v +=  1;
            clock_y_position = 100;
            clock_counter +=  2;
            trace("The clock counter is" + clock_counter);
            trace("The V is " +v);
            clock_display();
        }

    }



}
```

Under the go_back function the v is not really getting subtracted by 2 as it is needed to. That's what it shows in the trace anyway. Can somebody please help me out with it?

Comment: Can you give a better explanation of what your code is supposed to do?

Comment: Yep, I have a list of four clocks that needs to be displayed. And 2 of them needs to be displayed at a time. so I put them all in an array. At very beginning of the program i need 2 generated.  than I have 2 buttons one for showing the next 2 clocks and one for showing the previous 2 clocks. and that's pretty much it. in simple sentence just generating objects from an array. The main problem i am having is keeping track of where in the array exactly the program is at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below and do let me know if it works.
Pay attention to variable clock_Array_current_position. 
It keeps the pointer to array element where your code is at.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var clock_01:  Clock_one = new Clock_one ();
var clock_02:  Clock_two = new Clock_two ();
var clock_03:  Clock_three = new Clock_three ();
var clock_04:  Clock_four = new Clock_four ();

var socket_one:socket;
var clock_x_position = 100;
var clock_y_position = 100;

var clock_Array: Array = new Array ();
clock_Array.push(clock_01,clock_02,clock_03,clock_04);

var clock_counter = 2;
var clock_Array_current_position = 0;
clock_display();

function clock_display()
{
    var i = 0;
    for (i; i < clock_counter; i++) 
    {
        addChild(clock_Array[clock_Array_current_position + i]);
        clock_Array[clock_Array_current_position+i].x = clock_x_position;
        clock_Array[clock_Array_current_position+i].y = clock_y_position;
        clock_y_position += 300;
    }
}

function clock_remove()
{
    var i = 0; 
    for (i; i < clock_counter; i++)
    {
        removeChild(clock_Array[clock_Array_current_position+i]);
    }
}

go_previous.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, go_back);
go_next.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, go_forward);

function go_back(l:MouseEvent)
{
    if(clock_Array_current_position > 0)
    {
        clock_remove();
        clock_Array_current_position -= clock_counter; 
        clock_y_position = 100;
        clock_display();
    }
}

function go_forward(l:MouseEvent)
{
    if(clock_Array_current_position < clock_Array.length-clock_counter)
    {
        clock_remove();
        clock_Array_current_position += clock_counter;
        clock_y_position = 100;
        clock_display();
    }
}
```